# How to use a downloaded file (ionic 2)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cross-platform, ionic2

I am making an app for android/ios using ionic 2. I want to download a JSON file from a specific url on the net and then use it inside my app. This code is how I download:

```
const imageLocation = `my url for .json file`;  
if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
    targetPath = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + "data.json";
}
else if(this.platform.is('android')) {
    targetPath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "data.json";
    console.log(cordova.file.dataDirectory + "data.json");
}
fileTransfer.download(imageLocation, targetPath).then((entry) => {
    const alertSuccess = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: `Download Succeeded!`,
        subTitle: `file was successfully downloaded to: ${entry.toURL()}`,
        buttons: ['Ok']
    });
    alertSuccess.present();
}, (error) => {....
```

I want to use this downloaded file in my provider to fetch data from it. How can I do that?

Comment: This is a json file? Use http and don't store it. Cant store files in android apps anyway, no permissions

Comment: ` load(): any {
    if (this.data) {
      return Observable.of(this.data);
    } else {
      return this.http.get('assets/data/data.json')
        .map(this.processData);
    }
  } `
this is how i use the .json file that is inside the assets folder i want a solution to use the file i downloaded in this function if that possible

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the file, you can choose among many options:

- Save it in `localStorage`
- Save it in a SQLite database
- Use WebStorage
- Use new technologies like CouchDB, etc.

Alternatively, if the file is not very large, feel free to simply store it in a local variable of the provider, i.e. just add a setter method in your provider and pass the JSON object to it, so that it stores it in your provider. Note that in this case the data will be lost when the app is restarted.

Comment: load(): any {
    if (this.data) {
      return Observable.of(this.data);
    } else {
      return this.http.get('assets/data/data.json')
        .map(this.processData);
    }
  }
this is how i use the .json file that is inside the assets folder i want a solution to use the file i downloaded in this function if that possible

Comment: Perhaps I do not understand what you mean by `i want a solution to use the file` - you are already using it :) You already have the contents of the file, right? Please explain what exactly the problem is. I thought the problem is that the data disappears after app restart, and that is what my answer addresses.

Comment: the file assets/data/data.json comes packed with the app and i use it only for testing and that location is read only, i want to know how to download file to a location in android and ios and then i can use it in my provider in the same way i use the test file